# What is the equivalent Bash for this JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, bash, shell

What is the Bash version of the following JavaScript?

```
// url-safe base64 encoding
function b64(bytes){
    var str64 = typeof(bytes) === "string" ? window.btoa(bytes) : window.btoa(String.fromCharCode.apply(null, bytes));
    return str64.replace(/\//g, "_").replace(/\+/g, "-").replace(/=/g, "");
}
```

Especially the following part:

```
String.fromCharCode.apply(null, bytes)
```

Comment: we might be able to help if you included a small test case with sample input and expected output from that input. Right? Good luck.

Comment: @dknaack Do you really need to implement `b64()` in Bash? Can you not use the `base64` command?

Comment: What's the point of replacing all `/` and all `+` in a base64-encoded string when that string isn't going to have those characters?

Comment: @Biffen i already do this. I update my question.

Comment: @PSkocik Depends on the [variant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64#Variants_summary_table).

Comment: What about the `String.fromCharCode.apply(null, bytes)` ?

Comment: `base64 | tr /+ _- | tr -d =` ; the string should come on `stdin`

Answer (score 2):

```
#the string comes on stdin
base64 |      #encode
   tr /+ _- | #translate character sets
   tr -d =    #remove all =
```